# How to open a mask image as an array of pixel values consisting of only 0 or 1?

Tags: mask, semantic-segmentation

I'm going to implement a Pytorch Dataset which returns a minibatch of pairs (image, mask) in DataLoader. I've already implemented Dataset class as below :

```
class Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_path, y_path, transforms):
       self.x_paths= sorted([str(_) for _ in Path(x_path).rglob('*.png')])[:100]
       self.y_paths= sorted([str(_) for _ in Path(y_path).rglob(f'*_0.png')])[:100] 
       #print('loaded mask path:',self.y_paths[:3]) 
       self.transforms=transforms  
    def __len__(self):
       return len(self.x_paths)
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
       #print('imgfile: ',self.x_paths[idx],'mskfile: ',self.y_paths[idx])
       img=Image.open(self.x_paths[idx])
       msk=Image.open(self.y_paths[idx]).convert('L')
       #print('msk unique:',np.unique(np.array(msk)))
       if self.transforms:
           img=self.transforms(img)
           msk=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(512),transforms.ToTensor()])(msk)
       return (img,msk)
```

I want the mask file to be loaded as an PIL Image object, which has its image pixel values as only 0 or 1. But when I open the image file (.png) by PIL's Image.open() method, it opens up the grayscale mask image as an Image object having its image pixel values 0 to 255.

**Is there a way to open the image as an Image Object consisting only of 0 or 1 pixel values?**
Also, I'm considering a method of converting the Image's pixels (which could be easily converted into a numpy array) by **thresholding the pixel values over 0.5 as 1 and below as 0.** Does this matter much in the performance of the model training? (in other words, can I use it as my segmentation mask?)